# angular how to style differently the lowest value in table

Tags: angular, ng-class

I have a table in Angular that shows a list of items with prices. the prices is sorted from the DB so always the lowest price will be first. I want to style differently (color green) the first row of the bid amount column(all the other rows are red by default so i just need to style the first).
Another question is that I need to display the difference between the lowest bid to the other bids(will add picture to make this more understood)
stackblitz link :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lxngez
desired result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEeaR.jpg

I tried adding **`ngClass`** differently for the first index of bid. TotalPrice the but it didn't work :

```
<td [ngClass]="{'green-text': bid.TotalPrice[0]}">{{ bid.TotalPrice | currency }}</td>
```

I added picture for the desired result(2 things i need to achieve the different style and the difference between the lowest price to the other prices.

Comment: try adding styles to rows and extends styles however you want https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckecfw

Answer (score 1):

For the color, you can do it purly in css. You can add a .price class to the table cell and add a rule, which selects the first table row and overrides the price cell color

In Template:

```
<td style="color: red" class="price input-text">{{ bid.TotalPrice | currency }}</td>
```

In css:

```
#tableSortExample tbody tr:first-of-type .price {
   color: green!important;
}
```

Regarding the price you can simply add a conditional span in the case of the lowest price and in other cases

```
<td style="color: red" class="price input-text">{{ bid.TotalPrice | currency }}
    <span *ngIf="i === 0"> Lowest price.</span>
    <span *ngIf="i > 0"> {{bid.TotalPrice - auctionBidsData.auctionBids[0].TotalPrice | currency}}</span>
</td>
```

Comment: works great but new problem im encountering now that i can filter the table and always the first field is green and now i see that this approach isn't good because i need to style differently the lowest item and not the first item : https://imgur.com/a/B39smeU because after i filter the table the highest price gets the green color

Comment: in this case you can store the index of the lowest price on reordering in the component and apply styles and calculating based on this index. you will have to change the css selector (which targets the first child) and do an ngstyle or ngclass on the row with the lowest price

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this (pure angular implementation):

**HTML**

```
    <td style="color: red" class="input-text"
        [ngClass]="{ 'price-input-text': 'i == 0' }"
        [ngStyle]="{color: i == 0 ? 'green' : 'red'}">
      {{ bid.TotalPrice | currency }}
      <small *ngIf="i == 0">Lowest price</small>
    </td>
```

Comment: works great but new problem im encountering now that i can filter the table and always the first field is green and now i see that this approach isn't good because i need to style differently the lowest item and not the first item : https://imgur.com/a/PapQO9O because after i filter the table the highest price gets the green color

Comment: In that case use the css class instead of the index but You're gonna need to figure out what's the lowest price using JS on the component and probably flag that item.

Answer (score 0):

Use ngClass like this:

```
<td [ngClass]="{ low: i == 0, high: i > 1, other: condition(item, i) }">ABC</td>
```

It will add class `low` for first index class `high` for everything above second row and class `other` for those who condition is evaluated to true.

Just use those classes to style accordingly.
[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckecfw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below using **`[ngClass]`**.

**HTML**

```
<tr *ngFor="let bid of auctionBidsData.auctionBids; let i = index" class="pointer-hover"
    (click)="goToLiveAuction(auction.UID)">
  ...
  <td style="color: red" class="input-text" 
      [ngClass]="{ 'lowest': i === 0 }">{{ bid.TotalPrice | currency }}</td>
  ...
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
.lowest {
  color: green !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

**[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rkw6f1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)**

Answer (score 0):

Find the min value using reduce

```
this.minPrice=this.auctionBidsData.auctionBids.reduce(
        (min,b)=>min<b.TotalPrice?min:b.TotalPrice,
           this.auctionBidsData.auctionBids[0].TotalPrice)
```

and use in the td

```
 [style.color]="{bid.totalPrice==minPrice?'green':null"}
```